# Do event based asynchronous pattern implementation always capture the current synchronization context?

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous

I was looking through some code in Bart De Smet's C# 5.0 Unleashed book and while playing around with it using `WebClient`.

In the code below, I noticed that the callback was executed on the UI thread. I know that `WebClient.DownloadStringAsync` implementation of EAP captures the current `SynchronizationContext`, and was wandering whether all implementations of EAP do this as there appears to be no way to specify what `SynchronizationContext` to execute the callback on.

Here is the code in question:

```
    private void loadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var client = new WebClient();

        client.DownloadStringCompleted += (o, args) =>
            {
                if (args.Error != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        throw args.Error; // simply to restore structured exception handling?!
                    }
                    catch (WebException)
                    {
                        this.textBox.Text = "ERROR: " + args.Error.Message;
                    }

                    return;
                }

                // Already on the UI thread!
                this.textBox.Text = args.Result;
            };

        client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(@"http:\\www.rpmglobal.com"));
    }
```

Comment: you aren't guaranteed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, definitely not. `WebClient's` implementation *does* sniff the current `SynchronizationContext` when you make the call that will eventually trigger the event to notify you (e.g. `DownloadStringAsync`), but that's purely implementation specific and not a guarantee of EAP.